# How to bind below sample xml data to jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have below XML data which has **name** as the xml tag element which is actually  column names and this is repeated as many times as the cell values that needs to be populated in the rows. **Value**  tag element is actually the value of the rows to that column.

What I need to do is using the below xml I need to take all the name elements and make it as column. Note if the **property** tag contains url tag apart from name and value tag then we should make that column as hyper link column.

**INPUT**

With this example we should obtain one header row and 3 data rows.

```
<entry>
  <properties xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <property>
      <name>Accessed</name>
      <value>14.01.2016 12:20:08</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Case no.</name>
      <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?ID=200017</url>
      <value>16/00017</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Title</name>
      <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?ID=200017</url>
      <value>San Case 16</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Type</name>
      <value>Case</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Responsible person</name>
      <value>Administrator</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Responsible unit</name>
      <value>Products</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Status</name>
      <value>In progress</value>
    </property>
  </properties>
  <properties xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <property>
      <name>Accessed</name>
      <value>14.01.2016 12:20:08</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Case no.</name>
      <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?ID=200017</url>
      <value>16/00017</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Title</name>
      <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?ID=200017</url>
      <value>San Case 16</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Type</name>
      <value>Case</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Responsible person</name>
      <value>Administrator</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Responsible unit</name>
      <value>Products</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Status</name>
      <value>In progress</value>
    </property>
  </properties>
  <properties xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <property>
      <name>Accessed</name>
      <value>14.01.2016 12:20:08</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Case no.</name>
      <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?ID=200017</url>
      <value>16/00017</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Title</name>
      <url>http://localhost/locator.aspx?ID=200017</url>
      <value>San Case 16</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Type</name>
      <value>Case</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Responsible person</name>
      <value>Administrator</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Responsible unit</name>
      <value>Products</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>Status</name>
      <value>In progress</value>
    </property>
  </properties>
</entry>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problem are you having? It's not hard to find how to parse xml to array

Comment: @charlietfl Problem is i am not understanding how to will the JqGrid understand that name is the column name and value as the rows?

Comment: @Oleg I appreciate for the efforts that you have put to help and solve the problems of others. However if I mark the answers which has not met the requirement then it may mislead to other folks in stackoverflow.

Comment: loop through the data and create your columns array data....then after that initialize jQgrid

Comment: @SanjuRao: you account have "1 vote cast". It means that you find helpful only one answer/question on the whole stackoverflow. It sounds suspected. If you find my answers not corresponds your requirements then I would prefer to save my time. Probably somebody else will post more helpful answer on your questions.

Comment: @charlietfl that I am currently doing it. I was expecting that If I can give the url and get the setting done in jqgrid

Comment: for known columns probably can... but that isn't your case.

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are correct. If the column is know it would be very easy to give the column names and column models. However in my case I dunno the number of the column that is going to return nor number rows

Comment: so keep doing it the way you are currently doing it

Comment: Also I agree with @Oleg ... as a user of community who has asked a lot of questions and accepted very few I doubt that you haven't been helped out by quite a few of those answers

Comment: @charlietfl thank you very much. I posted this question if there is any possibility to know. However I am happy to know that I am on the right way :)

Answer (score 0):

After doing few investigation I found that this can be handled by altering the returned data and constructing the Json object with column data, column model and column names by looping it. I have done this by creating a Json object and then binding it to grid.

```
function xml2JsonInGridFormat(xml, visibleColoumns) {
                if (xml.length > 0) {
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)
                    var result = {};
                    var colData = new Array();
                    var colNames = new Array();
                    var colModels = new Array();
                    //Build column Name         
                    var NameProperties = xml[0].getElementsByTagName("name");
                    for (var j = 0; j < NameProperties.length; j++) {
                        var colName = NameProperties[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        colNames.push(colName);
                    }
                    //Build column Model
                    var Modelproperties = xml[0].getElementsByTagName("property");
                    for (var i = 0; i < Modelproperties.length; i++) {
                        var colModel = null;                     
                        colModel = {
                            'name': Modelproperties[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,                            
                            sortable: true,
                            unformat: !!Modelproperties[i].getElementsByTagName("url").length,
                            shrinkToFit: false,
                            hidden: HideColumn(Modelproperties[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue, visibleColoumns),
                            width: "120px"                          
                        }                        
                        colModels.push(colModel);                        
                    }
                    //Build Row Data                    
                    for (var i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) {
                        var rows = xml[i].getElementsByTagName("property");
                        var row = {};
                        for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                            var cellKey = "", cellValue = "";
                            if (rows[j].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0] != undefined)
                                cellKey = rows[j].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                            if (rows[j].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0] != undefined) {
                                if (rows[j].getElementsByTagName("url").length > 0)
                                    cellValue = buildURL($(rows[j].getElementsByTagName("url")).text(), HtmlEncode($(rows[j].getElementsByTagName("value")).text()));
                                else
                                    cellValue = HtmlEncode(rows[j].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); //rows[j].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                            }
                            row[cellKey] = cellValue;
                        }
                        colData.push(row);
                    }
                    result["ColNames"] = colNames;
                    result["ColModel"] = colModels;
                    result["ColData"] = colData;
                    return result;
                }
```